# googletest read write same file fails

Tags: c++, opencv, googletest

I have some test cases and they will all write some string to 'tmp.txt' and read it back. And the tests will fail. If I only test one test case at a time, or change the temp file name from 'tmp.txt' to some random generated filenames, the tests will pass. What is the possible reason for that? Are test cases of googletest running sequentially?

```
TEST(xxxx) {
  string s = generate_some_string();
  string filename = "tmp.txt";
  ofstream tmpFile(filename);
  tmpFile << s;
  tmpFile.close();
  cv::VideoCapture cap(filename);
  // read the content back using cap, and do some check
  remove(filename.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default googletest should run the tests in sequence; though there is a [special testrunner](https://github.com/google/gtest-parallel) that runs tests in parallel, and the test plugin for visual studio too can be configured to run tests in parallel.

My suspicion would rather lie on the `cv::VideoCapture cap(filename);` call - can you verify that the file is indeed closed when the call returns, or at the very latest when you call `remove(filename.c_str());`?

Comment: Thank you and I finally found the problem is not because gtest. Some controller else where makes the test parallel.

Comment: No problem, sorry that  could not (directly) help. If you feel the root cause (i.e. the controller elsewhere) is a not that uncommon setup, please post the solution as your own answer and accept that one, in case someone else runs across the same problem. (If the problem is rather specific to your setup and unlikely to occur for anyone else then there is less use to post it - i.e. "When using gtest with Tool X and our special internal test tool & runner Y..." is unlikely to happen outside your company)